# Change time format of HH:MM:SS

Tags: javascript, django, vuejs2, vue.js

I have an api served with django (django-rest-framework) which return a movie object and its related information into a Vue app. One of the information is the movie duration.

object:

```
{
    "movie_id": 13,
    "duration": "17:52:14",
    ...
    ...
},
```

component template:

```
<div id="movieDetailSynopsis">
    ...
    ...
    <p>Duration: {{movie.duration}}</p>
</div>
```

The duration is in this format

> HH:MM:SS
>
> eg: 02:22:08

But what I want it to look like is in this way

> 2h 22m

Is there anyway to achieve this in django or vuejs or javascript?

**update:**

Tried using filter globaly

main.js:

```
new Vue({
    router,
    components: {App},
    template: '<App/>',
    store,
    filters: {
        durationFormat(value) {
            const duration = moment.duration(value);
            return duration.hours() + 'h ' + duration.minutes() + 's';
        }
    }
}).$mount('#app');
```

inside the component template:

```
<div id="movieDetailSynopsis">
    ...
    ...
    <p>Duration: {{movie.duration | durationFormat}}</p>
</div>
```

But I get an error:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve filter: durationFormat
> (found in anonymous component - use the "name" option for better debugging messages.)

Comment: I would recommend to use moment.js for any date/time manipulation or format https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a good place to use a Vue filter. More info on filters [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Filters). You can register a filter globally or locally in your component.

Here's a global filter:

```
Vue.filter('formatTime', function(value) {
  if (value) {
    const parts = value.split(":");
    return +parts[0] + "h " + +parts[1] + "m";
  } else {
    return "unknown"
  }
});
```

And here's how you would use it in your template:

```
<p>Duration: {{movie.duration | formatTime}}</p>
```

Note: you can make the formatting function more robust - this is just a sample to get you started and demonstrate how it could be used in Vue. As mentioned in the comments, the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library is really good for date/time parsing and manipulation.

[Here's a sample (including using moment.js) in codepen](http://codepen.io/peterburrell/pen/WprOOY?editors=1010).

**Update (in response to comment)**

Try updating your main.js to register the filter like this:

```
// register global filter
Vue.filter('durationFormat', function(value) {
  const duration = moment.duration(value);
  return duration.hours() + 'h ' + duration.minutes() + 's';
});

new Vue({
    router,
    components: {App},
    template: '<App/>',
    store,
}).$mount('#app');
```

Comment: I tried using `filters` in the main Vue globaly, but I got errors `[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve filter: durationFormat (found in anonymous component - use the "name" option for better debugging messages.)`. I have updated the question. Now I am using filters localy. Could you maybe please give some advice? But thank you for the full answer!

Comment: Hmm... where are you using the filter? In the App component template? If so, try either registering the filter locally in your App component or globally using `Vue.filter()`. I think the problem is that you have defined the filter locally in the root Vue instance but are attempting to use it in a child component.

Comment: Yes I was using the filter locally in the root Vue instance. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some basic javascript like this:

```
var time = "02:22:08";
var timeConverted = parseInt(t.split(':')[0]) + 'h' + ' ' + parseInt(t.split(':')[1]) + 'm';
```

Answer (score 0):

I only know javascript way.try format() method instead.

```js
function format(time){
        return time.replace(/(?:0)?(\d+):(?:0)?(\d+).*/,'$1h $2m');
}

["23:12:15","02:03:05"].forEach(function(time){
  console.log(time+" ==> "+format(time));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own template tag:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def convert_time(value):
    t_list = [t for t in value.split(':')]
    return '{}h {}m'.format(int(t_list[0]), t_list[1])
```

And then use it in template:

```
{% load your_tags %}
<div id="movieDetailSynopsis">
  ...
  ...
  <p>Duration: {{movie.duration|convert_time}}</p>
</div>
```

For more information look in [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags).

Answer (score 0):

You may create a django tag filter. Your tagfilter.py

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def tagFilter(duration):
    d = duration.split(":")
    hh,mm,ss = d[0],d[1],d[2]
    return "%sh %sm %ss" % (hh,mm,ss) # If you don't want to show the seconds, you may remove it:
    # "%sh %sm" % (hh,mm)
```

Your django template:

```
<div id="movieDetailSynopsis">
...
...
<p>Duration: {{movie.duration|tagFilter}}</p>
```